# imagefield clickable in a gridview

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview, ajaxcontroltoolkit, vb.net-2010

i have this imagefield in a gridview

```
<asp:ImageField HeaderText="Image" DataImageUrlField="Image_Path" ControlStyle-Width="50" ControlStyle-Height="50"/>
```

the `image_path` is a column name from the database that retuns the image link

i need to make this field clickable so once i click on it i need to popup a form just like this field:

```
 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="View">
                <ItemTemplate> 
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton3" CommandName="Select" onClick="popup_click" class="table-actions-button ic-table-edit" runat="server"></asp:LinkButton>
                </ItemTemplate> 
 </asp:TemplateField>
```

i tried to put an image button instead of an image field but i'm always getting `submit query` instead of the image...

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Image">
                <ItemTemplate> 
                   <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1" runat="server" DataImageUrlFormatString="Image_Path" ControlStyle-Width="50" ControlStyle-Height="50"/>

                </ItemTemplate>
```

does anyone know how can i fix this?

Comment: So with `imagebutton` the issue is the picture not showing, not the fact that there is no `onclick` event, right?

Comment: @Amber the picture is not showing and `onclick` it is clickable but i'm not able to popup the form...

Comment: well, it not popping up the form is because in your `imagebutton` you don't have the `CommandName="Select" onClick="popup_click"` that you do have in your `linkbutton`. (which presumably works) also, as far as I know `DataImageUrlFormatString` is an `Imagefield` property, `ImageUrl` should do for `ImageButton`

Comment: @Amber well i tried the `imageurl` and still the image is not showing.. and i added `CommandName="Select" onClick="popup_click" ` for the image button and also it's not popping up..

Comment: Try formulating your imageUrl as `ImageURL='<%# Eval("Image_Path") %>'  `

Comment: @Amber still nothing :/